# Makefile match pattern in command

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to figure out how to access the matched pattern in a rule:

```
bin/my_target_float%.a: foo
    command -dtype float%
```

In other words, the rule gets instantiated for float16, float32, float64 and I'd like to run the command for the particular type of float. The percentage sign isn't expanded in this section of the rule and I couldn't figure out from the docs how to get the matched number. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of the [pattern stem `$*`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables)...

```
bin/my_target_float%.a: foo
        command -dtype float$*
```